# Automatic scrolling when the keyboard is opened

Tags: java, android, scroll, window-soft-input-mode

I want the screen to automatically scroll up when the keyboard opens, so that the user can see what he has written.
The solution I found was to change the manifest and use adjustPan or adjustResize. I used both of them but it still didn't work.
Where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".auth.LoginActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/img_login"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/login_back">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textColor="@color/customColor"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="User Name"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/customColor"
                    >
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/acLogin_edtUserName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/customColor"
                        />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/customColor"
                    >
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/acLogin_edtPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/customColor"
                        />


                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/customColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/acLogin_txtLogin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/acLogin_prgLoading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Don't have any account?"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/customColor"
                        android:textSize="16dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/acLogin_txtSignUp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="Sign Up"
                        android:textColor="@color/customColor"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                </LinearLayout>




            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I change manifest to:

```
 <activity android:name=".auth.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan | adjustResize"/>
```